# Yt-gem API call for account videos taking excessive time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using yt gem for my rails app, to get all the videos of a youtube account.

The code I am using is

```
        account = Yt::Account.new access_token: @user.youtube_access_token
        youtube_videos = []
        @videos =  account.videos
        @videos.each do |video|
            res1 = {}
            res1["provider"] = response["provider"]
            res1["video_id"] = video.id
            res1["url"] = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + video.id
            res1["thumbnail"] = video.thumbnail_url
            res1["title"] = video.title
            res1["description"] = video.description
            res1["published_at"] = video.published_at
            res1["duration"] = video.duration
            youtube_videos << res1
        end
```

Some basic Time.now() logs showed that the `@videos =  account.videos` statement takes about 1 second to complete and returns a Yt::Collections::Videos object which is as expected. However, the subsequent `@videos.each` loop takes about 1 second for each video present. Which is adding too much delay in my app.

My explanation is that each iteration in `@videos.each` results in  a separate API call that is why the loop takes so much time to execute. However I am unsure of this fact.

Is there a way to speed up the process of getting all videos from an account?

Comment: I don't know Ruby, so I don't see which part of the loop would invoke another API request. But for a start, you can verify this assumption by checking your machine's outgoing HTTP requests with a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler).

Comment: Also be advised that once you have a list of multiple video IDs, you can get the desired information for all of the IDs at once [by setting the `id` parameter of `videos.list` to a comma-separated list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#id).